# Configurar proyecto java EE en servidor glassfish

Tags: java, netbeans, web, glassfish, war

Tengo un proyecto Java EE Webapp, estoy en proceso de configurarlo en un servidor con glassfish 5, JDK8.0_172 y plesk como panel de control.

El proyecto se divide en 3, EAR EJB y web. Después de ejecutarlos en Netbeans 8.2 IDE, me generan unos archivos .ear y .war en el proyecto EAR y .war en el proyecto web. Esos archivos los subo al servidor de aplicaciones, a la carpeta autodeploy de glassfish. El archivo .ear me daba y sigue dando fallo (deployFailed), asi que subo el .war generado en la misma carpeta.

Despues de varios dias consigo que no me den error, pero solo se muestra la pantalla por defecto del servidor glassfish:

"Your server is now running
To replace this page, overwrite the file index.html in the document root folder of this server. The document root folder for this server is the docroot subdirectory......"

En la carpeta root del servidor(httpdocs) están las carpetas de los 3 proyectos(ear,ejb,web). ¿Alguna idea de qué puedo estar haciendo mal?

Muchas gracias.

EDIT:

Adjunto los errores del log del servidor glassfish al intentar hacer deploy del .ear:

"[javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.autodeploy] [tid: _ThreadID=92 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1536681698563] [levelValue: 900] [[ Attempt to create file /var/www/vhosts/ocium.net/appservers/glassfish-5x/domains/domain1/autodeploy/.autodeploystatus/ociumfinal-ear.ear failed; no further information.]]

Exception during lifecycle processing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve reference [Local ejb-ref name=chat.ChatResource/conversacionEjb,Local 3.x interface =com.eventos.ConversacionFacadeLocal,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session] because there are [2] ejbs in the application with interface com.eventos.ConversacionFacadeLocal.

Some of the possible causes: 1. The EJB bean class was packaged in an ear lib library (or through any other library mechanism which makes the library visible to all component modules), this makes all the component modules include this bean class indirectly. 2. The EJB bean class was packaged in a component module which references the EJB, either directly or indirectly through Manifest, WEB-INF/lib. The EJB bean class should only be packaged in the declaring ejb module and not the referencing modules. The referencing modules should only include EJB interfaces."

Comment: Saludos una consulta tienes agregado como dependencia cada proyecto EAR en EJB y EAR en web ??

Comment: Desafortunadamente la aplicación no la he hecho yo y esta no es una tecnologia con la que esté familiarizado, así que no sé si están agregados como dependencia. Como podría verlo?

Comment: ¿Qué URL estás usando?

Comment: ocium.net. He probado tanto el mapping web wild card como por ruta mapeandolo a la carpeta que contiene el proyecto web. Con este ultimo me muestra el index del proyecto, pero sin el java ejecutandose.

Comment: Normalmente, dentro del `.ear` tendrás toda la aplicación (`.war`, `.jar` que no esten en `.war`). Puedes abrir y ver la estructuras de todos los archivos como si fueran ficheros zip. Mira el log del servidor para ver en que URL se deployan los archivos.

Comment: Creo que se puede ver aqui:

[2018-09-11T18:01:38.563+0200] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [NCLS-DEPLOYMENT-02041] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.autodeploy] [tid: _ThreadID=92 _ThreadName=AutoDeployer] [timeMillis: 1536681698563] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Attempt to create file /var/www/vhosts/ocium.net/appservers/glassfish-5x/domains/domain1/autodeploy/.autodeploystatus/ociumfinal-ear.ear failed; no further information.]]

Comment: El error parece estar aquí:

  Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve reference [Local ejb-ref name=chat.ChatResource/conversacionEjb,Local 3.x interface =com.eventos.ConversacionFacadeLocal,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=,refType=Session] because there are [2] ejbs in the application with interface com.eventos.ConversacionFacadeLocal.

Comment: (continuación):
Some of the possible causes: 
1. The EJB bean class was packaged in an ear lib library (or through any other library mechanism which makes the library visible to all component modules), this makes all the component modules include this bean class indirectly. 
2. The EJB bean class was packaged in a component module which references the EJB, either directly or indirectly through Manifest, WEB-INF/lib. 
The EJB bean class should only be packaged in the declaring ejb module and not the referencing modules. The referencing modules should only include EJB interfaces.

Comment: @RaulCacacho si están las dependencias, ejb en "Dependencies" y web en "Non-classpath Dependencies"

Comment: @Rodrigo Pérez López pues yo lo pongo siempre en el pom.xml, revisa si tu proyecto los tiene porque solo debes de subir el war al glasfish